# Creating a form in IPFS for users to enter data

Tags: solidity, ipfs

I wanted to create a website and upload it onto the IPFS for users to upload data (like their picture, name etc.).

But how exactly can I capture all details user upload, get the IPFS Hash produced and then put down the hash in my solidity contract to store the hash on the ethereum blockchain?

Any links, or comments will be greatly appreciated. Sorry if the question is a bit dumb.

Comment: Hello Rahul, are you able to query JSON data based on some attributes from IPFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about user information, it can be very convinient to store it in JSON format.
I have example how to interact with JSON object in ipfs, how to get hash, store it  and then retrieve it from smart contract:

**MyContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MyContract {

  string public ipfsHash;

  function setHash(string _ipfsHash) external {
    ipfsHash = _ipfsHash;
  }
}
```

**test.js**

```
const ipfs = require("nano-ipfs-store").at("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001");
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract")

async function test() {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    name: "JSON Statehem",
    link0: "stackexchange.com",
    link1: "github.com",
    link2: "myfacebook.com"
  })

  const ipfsHash = await ipfs.add(data)
  const instance = await MyContract.deployed()

  await instance.setHash.sendTransaction(ipfsHash)

  let returnedHash = await instance.ipfsHash.call()

  console.log(ipfsHash)
  console.log(returnedHash)

  console.log(JSON.parse(await ipfs.cat(returnedHash)))

}

test()
```

You can store ipfs hash in `bytes` type in Solidity, but I prefer to store it in `string` because I won't have to make any convertion while retrieving value from `bytes`.

---

What about images, you will have to create buffer of the image and then simply upload it to ipfs using `.add`. It will return hash which you can store as in example above.

Comment: Wow, thanks!
One thing I didn't quite grasp:
So, does it work if say I create a website/form of a kind asking for user details, and then do what you suggested with those details? 
OR DO you reckon there is a shorter way?

Comment: @RahulKothari I think the most optimized way is to get all user information at one time. Just because you will pay gas for one ethereum transaction instead of storing ipfs hash of every input field. This is actually quite short way, as you will only need to replace variables in the code above with `$("#input").val()`.

Comment: Right! Just another follow-up question - how exactly should I get the user information? I mean through a solidity contract? or a website? or which method?

Comment: @RahulKothari get user information through standard input frontend form. When retrieving data just call `ipfsHash` from contract (free call, because we are not changing the state) and when you get hash retrieve data from ipfs with `ipfs.cat()`. After that simply access data as a normal json and output it wherever you want on your website.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate you boiling it down to this simple level.
I am however unsure of what exactly this means: `const ipfs = require("nano-ipfs-store").at("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001");`

How exactly does it link the file to ipfs?

Comment: @RahulKothari this line just imports the nano-ipfs module and connects to infura host. Adding file is fone with `ipfs.add(data)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73004/discussion-between-rahul-kothari-and-roman-frolov).

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39659/no-output-when-writing-data-to-ipfs-and-storing-its-hash-through-solidity/39698?noredirect=1#comment44444_39698 -> the method you gave somehow doesn't seem to work! Can you show me where I went wrong?

Comment: Hello @RomanFrolov, are you able to query JSON data based on some attributes from IPFS?