# No output when writing data to IPFS and storing its hash through Solidity

Tags: truffle, ipfs

So I am using truffle.
Following from [Creating a form in IPFS for users to enter data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39141/creating-a-form-in-ipfs-for-users-to-enter-data/39205#39205) [check the code in answer], doing some changes:

Contract name - IpfsContract.sol
test.js uses the following JSON Structure within the test():

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
        name: "Rahul Kothari",
        age: "21",  // maybe "21"?
        sex: "male"
})
```

My `1_initial_migration.js` and `truffle-config.js` files work fine!

Using truffle develop, on CMD I run `truffle compile` `truffle migrate`. Works perfectly! I then run `truffle test` and it displays: `0 passing (1ms)` in green. No other output although, my test.js used console.log!

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no files in test folder. As per truffle when you run test with out options it will look into test folder inside your project. Make sure you have test.js inside `test`. If there are no files then it will execute 0 test case's so that's reason it showing 0 test cases passed.

Comment: But I do have a test.js file in my test folder

Comment: @RahulKothari Can you paste your test log.

Comment: `const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const node = new IPFS()
const IpfsContract = artifacts.require("IpfsContract")
async function test() {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        name: "Rahul Kothari",
        age: "21",  // maybe 21?
        sex: "male"
    })
    const ipfsHash = await node.add(data)
    const instance = await IpfsContract.deployed()

    await instance.setHash.sendTransaction(ipfsHash)
    let returnedHash = await instance.ipfsHash.call()
    console.log(ipfsHash)
    console.log(returnedHash)
    console.log(JSON.parse(await node.cat(returnedHash)))
}
test()`

Comment: Sorry that the thing looks a bit messy, but the comments here cant be long

Comment: Remove async keyword, Because its a async method it will execute method background and it will take time to deploy contract until you did't get any logs.

Comment: But await only works within async functions right?

Also, it still doesnt work

Comment: const IPFS = require('ipfs') const node = new IPFS() const IpfsContract = artifacts.require("IpfsContract") function test() { const data = JSON.stringify({ name: "Rahul Kothari", age: "21", // maybe 21? sex: "male" }) const ipfsHash = node.add(data) const instance = IpfsContract.deployed() instance.setHash.sendTransaction(ipfsHash) let returnedHash = instance.ipfsHash.call() console.log(ipfsHash) console.log(returnedHash) console.log(JSON.parse(await node.cat(returnedHash))) } test()

Comment: Nope, still says `0 Passing`