# IPFS code needing extra JS Scripts with Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, ipfs

So I created a truffle folder for solidity, wrote down the basic test.js and ipfsContract.sol needed ([Creating a form in IPFS for users to enter data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39141/creating-a-form-in-ipfs-for-users-to-enter-data)). HOWEVER, on doing `truffle test` I get `0 passing` in green, although I do ask test.js to print out the hash code!

[I also do one edit in test.js - 
`const IPFS = require('ipfs')  // importing IPFS module and instantiating it.
const node = new IPFS()`]

Reading various articles on the net, I am thinking if I need to create an extra .js file outside the truffle directory to make it work. But I could be wrong!
ANy help?

Comment: You have to do the hash conversion in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Js implementation for IPFS

Refer this :- https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api

Connect IPFS as follows :-

```
   var ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api')

   // connect to ipfs daemon API server
   var ipfs = ipfsAPI('localhost', '5001', {protocol: 'http'})
```

I have given a code for adding a textinput into ipfs for your reference.
The given code will convert the input to hash and passed it into the contract function.

```
 storeTest:function(amount){

     ipfs.add(new Buffer(amount), function (err, res){
           if(err || !res) return console.error("ipfs add error", err, res);
           else{

              res.forEach(function(text) {
                    console.log('successfully stored', text.hash);
                    //Storing hash in blockchain                   
                               SimpleStorage.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                                  console.log("Initializing set function");
                                  instance.set(text.hash,{from: account, gas: 3000000})
                                          .then(function(v){ 
                                           console.log("Function  set Executed");

                                   });

                            }).catch(function(e) {
                                          console.log(e);
                            });  

             });
           }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Right thanks! But did yu write all this in test.js provided by truffle?

Comment: @RahulKothari I didn't get.

Comment: I mean, can it be written in test.js (that comes in the test folder when we do truffle init)

ALSO, why do we have `amount` in the first line?

Comment: Test.js deals with testing of solidity.you have to add the above code in app.js to convert your input into hash.amount is the input from frontend,which is used for creating hash.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Lastly, why do you mention `amount` in the first line?

Comment: I am passing the text input 'amount' as param.Did you mean that?

Comment: Then shouldn't it be `sotreTest:function('amount')`. Also what does this do : `then(function(v){ `

Comment: What is `textaddress`?
Also,
I saved this in `app.js`. Now how exactly do I run it? Do I call the `jsipfs daemon` and then on `truffle console` I do `$ truffle compile` and `$ truffle migrate`

Comment: I have edited textaddress to text.hash,it was my mistake. The variable v returns the hash of contract function execution.I have added some more logic into it in my code.I have posted the answer with your requirements.

Comment: You have start ipfs daemon in one terminal.And do the commands in truffle as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks!! Also, what must be added into test.js? The confusion is perhaps because I don't really understand how to integrate app.js with the other folders created by truffle

Comment: you don't have to worry about the integration.Truffle integrated webpack with it for doing all these.Test.js deals with the testing of solidity language.

Comment: Because when I did open js-ipfs daemon and did `truffle compile, truffle migrate`, nothing happens (and my test.js is obviously empty)

Comment: you don't have to bother with test.js....The command is ```ipfs daemon```..

Comment: I have downloaded js-ipfs version. So the command for me will be `jsipfs daemon`. But error output comes when I go to localhost:9090 (which is the port my daemon uses)